# How to use square bracket inside PHP Regex class?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to add [ and ] in my validation Regex that already accept all numeric, underscore, period and alphanumeric character.

Here is the regex working:
     $regex = "^[._a-zA-Z0-9-]*$";

But when I try :

```
$regex = "^[.\\[\\]_a-zA-Z0-9-]*$";
```

or

```
$regex = "^[.\[\]_a-zA-Z0-9-]*$";
```

It doesn't work (I have read to double escape in PHP for bracket but it doesn't work!

I use `eregi`.

Any idea?

Test :

```
<?php
//$regex = "^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*$";
$regex = "^[.\\[\\]_a-zA-Z0-9-]*$";
echo("1".(eregi($regex, "patrick")?"True":"False"));//Should return True
echo("<br>");
echo("2".(eregi($regex, "p@trick")?"True":"False"));
echo("<br>");
echo("3".(eregi($regex, "pat rick")?"True":"False"));
echo("<br>");
echo("4".(eregi($regex, "patr'ick")?"True":"False"));
echo("<br>");
echo("5".(eregi($regex, "pAtr'ick")?"True":"False"));
echo("<br>");
echo("6".(eregi($regex, "pAtr_ick")?"True":"False"));//Should return True
echo("<br>");
echo("7".(eregi($regex, "pA-tr_ick")?"True":"False"));//Should return True
echo("<br>");
echo("8".(eregi($regex, "pAaAta   atrack")?"True":"False"));
echo("<br>");
echo("9".(eregi($regex, "pA%k")?"True":"False"));
echo("<br>");
echo("10".(eregi($regex, "patrick.second")?"True":"False")); //Should return True
echo("<br>");
echo("11".(eregi($regex, "[Pat]Rick")?"True":"False"));//Should return True
echo("<br>");
?>
```

Comment: Don't use eregi as it's being removed from the PHP core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former one should work. You need to use two backslashes: one for the regular expression escape and one for the string escape. Just see how it gets evaluated:

```
echo "^[.\\[\\]_a-zA-Z0-9-]*$"; // => ^[.\[\]_a-zA-Z0-9-]*$
```

And that’s exactly what you need.

---

**Edit**    Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) instead:

```
preg_match("/^[.\\[\\]_a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/i", $str)
```

I don’t know why this regular expression doesn’t work with `eregi`, but it does with `preg_match`. Futhermore the [POSIX ERE functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.regex.php) are deprecated and will be removed by PHP 6 in favor of the [PCRE functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php). Note that PCRE regular expressions use [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to enclose the regular expression and separate it from the [modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: Doesn't work with the code posted in the question (I just edited it with a snippet)

Comment: It works with preg_match with : $regex = "/^[\[\]._a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/";

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `$` if it's within double quotes.

Eg.:

```
$regex = "^[.\\[\\]_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\$";
```

Comment: Doesn't work with the code posted in the question (I just edited it with a snippet)

Comment: You're right - Seems that PHP is smart enough to understand the missing backslash. Try using `preg_match` instead. `ereg` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but a helpful tip: Use single quotes around your regexes (if they don't require php parsing), so you don't have to do an extra layer of escaping. Only a single quote requires escaping in a single-quoted string. [(php strings)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Also, the `ereg` family of functions is [on its way out](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php). Why not use preg_match, with an 'i' after the closing slash to indicate a case-insensitive match?

Answer (score 0):

You can't escape characters in a bracket expression when using `ereg` functions. Use this pattern instead:

```
$regex = "^[]._[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$";
```

You can understand why it works by reading the part on bracket expressions in [regex man page](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=7&topic=regex).

Anyway, it would be better to just switch to [PCRE functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) instead, as `eregi` is now deprecated in PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping inside brackets does not work with ereg (it treats \ as literal char).
']' should always be placed as first char in brackets and '[' can be anywhere else:

```
$regex = "^[]._[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$";
```

However you better migrate to preg_match, because ereg is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and will be removed in PHP6.